# Why are some files named 'www'?

Tags: cordova

I have spent the last month playing around with Cordova app building and I have noticed that many established cordova plugin repositories contain files named 'www'. Could someone explain to me what the 'www' represents or stands for and what type of files should be contained in these folders? TYIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking ..  When creating a Cordova app, a **www** directory is created.  This is considered the "working directory".  And for certain apps, like Phonegap apps say, this www directory is where all the "front facing" web related files reside.  Files that contain JS, CSS, or HTML to be read by a web browser or web interface.  An example of Cordova App setup and creation can be found [HERE](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/)  --  You can see how during app creation, Cordova creates a **www** directory.